# Rails glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf 404 (Not Found)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, font-awesome, glyphicons

I am receiving an error in my chrome console saying "GET https://website.net/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular-10ceae8b6ff60bf6e0162ec5e950bf8b.ttf 404 (Not Found)"

However when I ssh into my server I see the file there located in the rails public/assets directory.

I am not sure how to debug or fix this but the font awesome icon is not rendering on the page.

Thanks!

Comment: I see that you are using ``glyphicons halflings`` is there a reason why you're not using bootstrap's glyphicon components? http://getbootstrap.com/components/

Comment: I believe its coming from this library, https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker

Comment: Are you precompiling for the production environment? Looks like you may be precompiling on your local machine whilst it's still in development mode